# How come my media query styles aren't changing?

Tags: html, css, web, format

I'm trying to test my media query code by adding a background color to the header in my tablet view. When I try and change it back to the desktop view it still stays red even though I didn't include red as a background colour in my desktop view media query.. Can anyone offer any advice?

```css
/* For tablet: */

@media only screen and (min-width: 601px) {
  
    /* Header section  */
 
   header {
        margin: 40px auto;
       background-color: red;
      
    }
    
 
    
} /* Closing tablet query - DO NOT DELETE */



/* For desktop*/

@media only screen and (min-width: 992px) {

  .col-l-1 {width: 8.33%;}
  .col-l-2 {width: 16.66%;}
  .col-l-3 {width: 25%;}
  .col-l-4 {width: 33.33%;}
  .col-l-5 {width: 41.66%;}
  .col-l-6 {width: 50%;}
  .col-l-7 {width: 58.33%;}
  .col-l-8 {width: 66.66%;}
  .col-l-9 {width: 75%;}
  .col-l-10 {width: 83.33%;}
  .col-l-11 {width: 91.66%;}
  .col-l-12 {width: 100%;}
    
    
/* Header section  */

    header {
        width: 1100px;
        margin: 40px auto;
    }
    
    .logo {
        margin-left: 290px;
        margin-top: 80px;
    }
    
    nav {
         margin-top: 60px;
         margin-left: 240px;
            
    }  

} /*closing for desktop*/
```

Comment: Have you tried using max-width instead of min-width?

Comment: yeah.. still not working... now its adding red to the mobile even though i haven't styled that part yet

Comment: Do you have any HTML to help with troubleshooting?

Comment: I just edited the code, the brackets ending both media queries were missing... I gather this must be a mistake while pasting the code to the question, but I'd also urge you to verify in your stylesheet that everything is properly closed

Comment: @lucasreta I have the closing brackets in the css :/ Ill upload more

Comment: @codeninja yes hold on

Comment: @HannahdeGuzman I figured, but rather safe than sorry...

Comment: there must be some rule that I am unaware of because my teacher did it like this

Comment: @HannahdeGuzman as I replied to your comment I realized the issue, in my answer I provide 2 possible solutions to the problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem you are having is due to the media query, which specifies `min-width: 601px`. For all screens 601 pixels or larger, the properties assigned to each selector will be true, so all `header` elements will have a `background-color: red;`, unless otherwise specified, in all screens with a width 601 pixels or larger.

To avoid seeing the red background color in your desktop sizes, you should either:

1 - Overwrite the property on the desktop media query:

```css
@media only screen and (min-width: 992px) {
    header {
        width: 1100px;
        margin: 40px auto;
        background-color: transparent; /* or whatever you'd like */
    }
}
```

2 - Or limit your tablet media query to tablet sizes by adding a max-width condition:

```css
@media only screen and (min-width: 601px) and (max-width: 992px) {
  ...
}
```

Comment: OMGGG thanks so much! yeah I have a lot more content on the web page so I used your second answer and it worked.. I'm a beginner at this stuff so thank you

Comment: @HannahdeGuzman great to hear! If my answer helped you, please consider accepting it and/or upvoting it.

Answer (score 0):

So I think what's happening is both styles are being applied, and since the 992px doesn't specify a background-color it defaults to using red. Using `max-width` can eliminate that from happening. See below for a simple example:

```css
@media only screen and (max-width: 601px) {
  header {
    width: 1100px;
    margin: 40px auto;
    background-color: red;
  }
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 992px) {
  header {
    width: 1100px;
    margin: 40px auto;
  }
}
```

```html
<header>Header</header>
<nav>Nav</nav>
```

Answer (score 0):

CSS works with the cascade style flow. The order of the rules will override the next rule if they are pointing the same  css rule. If they doesn't the last rule will be maintained (it doesn't matter if the rules are in a media query). Resume: the media query doesn't override all the rules, only override the rules that you defined and it'll maintain the other rules as the last value in relation of the order in the css file.